# Python Plus One question edge case and efficiency improvement

Tags: python

**Question**: Given a non-empty array of decimal digits representing a non-negative integer, increment one to the integer.

The digits are stored such that the most significant digit is at the head of the list, and each element in the array contains a single digit.

You may assume the integer does not contain any leading zero, except the number 0 itself.

**My Solution**:

```
class Solution:
def plusOne(self, digits: List[int]) -> List[int]:
    #n=len(digits)
    numStr=""
    for i in digits: 
        numStr+=str(i)
        
    newNum=int(numStr)+1
    newNumStr=str(newNum)
    l=len(newNumStr)
    #print(newNum)
    #print(l)
    for i in range(0,l):
        digits[i]=newNum%10
        print(digits[i])
        newNum=int(newNum/10)
        
    return digits[::-1] #reverse the array
```

For some reason, My solution works correctly eg for input [1,2,3] the output is [1,2,4] but it doesn't work for the input edge case of [9] and [9,9] etc. Im not sure why?
Also, my solution doesn't seem to be very efficient. Is there a more efficient way to solve this question?

Expected output:

```
input [2,3] gives output [2,4]
input [2,3,7] gives output [2,3,8]
input [9] gives output [1,0]
```

Comment: can you share input data and expected output. It will make it easy for us to review.

Comment: Your solution is indeed very inefficient, but on top of that (assuming this is some kind of course assignment) I doubt that converting the array to a string and then converting the string to an int, adding 1 and then reversing the process is the solution they are looking for. Why not increment the digits directly, like you would 'by hand'?

Comment: @Grismar, But in that case, it is easy to do in the following case: input [2,3] gives output [2,4] and easy for case: input [2,9] gives output [3,0] but not easy for case: input [9] gives output [1,0] (i.e the problem is how do I extend the size of the array?)

Answer (score 0):

Convert to a string and join, convert to an int and add one, convert back

Hacky Code Below:

```
return [int(i) for i in str(int("".join([str(i) for i in digits])) + 1)]
```

Less Hacky, More ugly!:

```
def increment(start):
    start.reverse()
    result = []
    carry = 1
    for v,i in enumerate(start):
        i += carry
        if i == 10:
            carry = 1
            result.append(0)
        else:
            result += [*[i]+start[v+1:]]
            result.reverse()
            return result
    else:
        if carry:
            result.insert(0, 1)
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @TheLazyScripter that it's not pretty, but it doesn't have to be quite as ugly:

```
class Solution:
    def plusOne(self, digits: List[int]) -> List[int]:
        carry = 1
        result = []
        for n in reversed(digits):
            result.append((n + carry) % 10)
            carry = (n + carry) // 10
        while carry:
            result.append(carry % 10)
            carry = carry // 10
        return list(reversed(result))
```

What I like about it is that it works for any `carry`, so if you want to write `plusAny` instead of `plusOne`, you hardly need to change anything.

By the way, you normally shouldn't name your methods like `plusOne` but rather `plus_one`, but I'm assuming you're being asked to name it that.

Answer (score 0):

Concatenate the elements in the list as strings, then convert it to an int and add 1. Then do str again and finish the job with list comprehension!

```
class Solution:
    def plusOne(self, digits):
        s = str(int("".join(map(str, digits))) + 1)
        result = [i for i in s]
        return result
```